# Spring configuration using Java annotations

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I have started working on an inventory management system (web application) using [Spring Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework) 3.1.1** and would like to configure Spring Framework using Java annotations. I searched Google, but I could not find a suitable example showing how to configure Spring Framework using Java annotations in a web application. Where is there a proper example or tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Framework references are comprehensive. Refer to the Spring reference material, *[3.11 Java-based container configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java)*.

Answer (score 1):

Another option to consider is to use Java based configuration. It is more readable, and is easier than annotations.

[Spring Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java)

[Simple Example using Java based configuration](http://anandsekar.github.io/spring-configuration-in-java/)